# Dynamically change the value of a textbox on clicking of its corresponding checkbox in ng-repeat in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

This question might sound very basic to many of you, but please pardon me as I am newbie to angularjs.

Basically what I am trying to do is changing the value of a corresponding textbox on click to its corresponding checkbox.

Here is My Markup Code:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Select</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Phone</th>
      <th>No. Of Chits</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="entity in UnassignedMembers ">
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="entity.isChecked" ng-change="selectEntity(entity)">
      </td>
      <td>{{ entity.Name}}</td>
      <td>{{ entity.PhoneNo}}</td>
      <td>
        <input type="number" min="1" ng-model="entity.Count">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to assign a value of "1" to the entity. Count on check of entity.isChecked.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to assign valaue to `entity.Count` like following

```
$scope.selectEntity = function(entity){
    if(entity.isChecked){
        entity.Count = 1;
    }else{
        entity.Count = 0; // or null
    }
};


<tr ng-repeat="entity in UnassignedMembers " >
   <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="entity.isChecked" ng-change="selectEntity(entity)"></td>
   <td>{{ entity.Name}}</td>
   <td>{{ entity.PhoneNo}}</td>
   <td><input type="number" min="1"  ng-model="entity.Count"></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Thanks Brother it really helped!! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it even without the function in controller,

HEre is the code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="">

<table>
<tr>
   <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="entity.isChecked" ng-change="selectEntity(entity);entity.Count = entity.isChecked ? 1 : ''"></td>
   <td>{{ entity.Name}}</td>
   <td>{{ entity.PhoneNo}}</td>
   <td><input type="number" min="1"  ng-model="entity.Count"></td>
</tr>
</table>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**Please run the above Snippet**

Please tell me which value to fill in checkbox. So that I can change the code accordingly.

[**HERE IS A WORKING DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/UMJalQfBAe3vk6r4OZpK?p=preview)